# bootstrap modal not working in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

Bootstrap 3.3 not working moodal link in dropdown menu.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasaras/wkc5md23/6/)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-list">Add New Link</a>
```

If I remove this line from js modal works perfect, but dropdown menu collapses after click. Dropdown menu must be opened.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you should do to make modal show in dropwdown:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('[data-toggle=modal]')) {
        $($(e.target).data('target')).modal()
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wkc5md23/8/

Comment: Works like a charm, don't forget to wait for the document to load, otherwise jQuery won't find the dropdown-menu's  
`(function($){
                $(window).on("load",function(){
                    $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        if ($(e.target).is('[data-toggle=modal]')) {
                            $($(e.target).data('target')).modal()
                        }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the jQuery function `$('.dropdown-menu').click` and make sure the dropdown menu is shown like this:

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="">I am a item</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-list">Add New Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.list li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Solution 1. Purely CSS, show dropdown on hover:

```
.list li:hover ul {
    display: block
}
```

Solution 2. Just jQuery, show dropdown by click:

Use a CSS class to show the dropdown:

```
.open { display: block }
```

And do this with jQuery:

```
$('.list li a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by adding a Button element instead of DropdownItem inside of DropdownMenu and it worked for me. I used reactstrap (and hence elements starting with caps) but it should probably have similar behavior to bootstrap or react-bootstrap. This did not close the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Put Modal after Dropdown-menu

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="NewGroup" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="NewGroupLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```