# Data-target modal is not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When i am clicking on login option ,my login popup model is not displaying ,where is the problem in this code.

```
     <li> <a href="#" class=" pull-right"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>LogIn</a></li>
```

data target code is here,after clicking on login tnis model is called for pop up but pop model is not coming.

```
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content col-md-8">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i> User Login</h4>
                </div>
                <form method="post" id="login_form" action="<?= site_url('api/login') ?>" >
                    <!--?php echo form_open('welcome/checkLogin'); ?-->
                    <div class="modal-body with-padding">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <label>Username *</label>
                                    <!--input type="text" name="email"/-->

                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="email" class="form-control required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <label>Password *</label>
                                    <!--input type="password" name="pass"/-->
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="pass" class="form-control required" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="error" id="logerror"></div>
                    <!-- end Add popup  -->  
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
                        <!--input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/-->
                        <button type="submit" id="btn-login" value="Login" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary  pull-right btn-xs">Login</button>              
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: your fourth to last closing div tag is malformed '</div'

Comment: i have correct that error but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You must assign an ID "myModal" to the modal content.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal-dialog">
```

This allows your JavaScript to target the `div`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue from an ul with many li, i found a good answer by someone in js:

```
if ($(e.target).is('[data-toggle=modal]')) {
        $($(e.target).data('target')).modal()
}
```

from link: [bootstrap modal not working in dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697851/bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-dropdown-menu)